# How to get link to Square Store product using Square Connect Catalog API

Tags: square-connect

My client has an online store with Square. A direct product link, for example, is:

https://squareup.com/store/barbara-westfall/item/vermillion-wave

I am using the catalog API to successfully download a list of all her products - getting the name, description, price, image url and item id. Example:

```
{
    "name": "Vermillion Wave",
    "description": "Art Glass by Barbara Westfall, M.F.A.\n14\"w x 18\"h\nFused glass. Colors: Red, Orange, Iridescent blue\nIncludes hardware for wall mount",
    "visibility": "PUBLIC",
    "available_online": true,
    "category_id": "BJBBZFC4XG7OJNTKTHZJIXZN",
    "ordinal": 6,
    "tax_ids": [
        "FNLAO42DW2BZ7QBH6EOFG724"
    ],
    "image_url": "https://square-production.s3.amazonaws.com/files/2ccc245b18a52e82cd3edf524cf7ca52131fc400/original.jpeg",
    "variations": [
        {
            "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
            "id": "573MTFRL37CO2YX5LCAPKYKF",
            "updated_at": "2018-02-04T05:14:27.391Z",
            "version": 1517721267391,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "catalog_v1_ids": [
                {
                    "catalog_v1_id": "38b4d712-3882-45c7-982f-eaa3ea042e32",
                    "location_id": "8MVKB4PVKKAF9"
                }
            ],
            "present_at_all_locations": false,
            "present_at_location_ids": [
                "8MVKB4PVKKAF9"
            ],
            "item_variation_data": {
                "item_id": "CRBWP5INOYUN46TTQPLWNQC6",
                "name": "Regular",
                "ordinal": 1,
                "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
                "price_money": {
                    "amount": 24500,
                    "currency": "USD"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "product_type": "REGULAR",
    "skip_modifier_screen": false
}
```

I would like to provide a link to the online store item based on the data from the catalog API, but I see no information in this item data that would allow. The url in this example does happen to be lower case version of the name with a dash, however most of her items have a very different name than in the slug.

Is there any other option for getting that url so I can provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look the the example link you provided and it appears that your client is using the Square free online store. Unfortunately the Catalog API doesn't provide a link to the free online store.